# Powershell : How to convert "ISO" char to UTF8?

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8

I use this function to download some RSS feeds an write it in an Excel file :

```powershell
Function Get-RSS {
param ([string]$url)
$Results = @()
$wc = New-Object Net.WebClient
$wc.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

[xml]$resp = $wc.DownloadString("$url")
$article = $resp.rss.channel.item

foreach ($in in $article) {
    [string]$description = $in.description.InnerText -replace "<.*?>"
    $Results += Set-News -Title $in.title -Content $description -PublishDate $in.pubDate -Link $in.OrigLink
}
return $Results
```

}

Download work correctly but I have a problem with specific chars like this :

> &#8230 ;
>   &#8217 ;
>   ...

I see that in Excel, how can I convert it to see char behind this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the html characters. Change

```powershell
[xml]$resp = $wc.DownloadString("$url")
```

to

```powershell
[xml]$resp = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($wc.DownloadString("$url"))
```

If you are using PS2 then add `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web` at the top of you script/function to import the required .NET binary.